# Using SSRS Native and SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I need to get a c# project to look at SSRS reports but complete newbie to SSRS.  Using SQL Server Express on my machine and whilst I installed Reporting Services - Native I can't upgrade the management tools to Complete to further edit and add reports to SSRS.  Have it open in IE and no report builders and no BI Studio so I can't work out how to add any reports.

Can anyone advise me how I can add reports to SSRS when only using SQL Server Express or is it simply the case it can't be done with SQL Server Express?

Comment: Nowadays you can have BI tools installed in Visual Studio and develop reports there

Comment: As a Nuget package or as a project template?

Comment: you need `SQL Server Express with Advanced Services` , only sql server express does not have SSRS in it.

Comment: @M.Ali I have it installed but no report builder option so I can't see how else to create reports.  You can apparently use management studio to connect but you need complete instead of basic management tools which doesn't appear to be available with express

Comment: ah , `Report Builder` is only available in `Developers Edition` or `Standard` and upwards . There is no Report Builder in any of the free sql server editions.

Comment: Thought as much, any ideas on how to add a report if report builder is unavailable? Even if it's just importing one

Comment: If you already have an .RDL file you should be able to deploy it to the SSRS server using the SSRS WebSite Upload button.